# Зачем в Drupal 8 функция скрытия поля title?

Tags: drupal

Поле Title обязательно к заполнению. Для чего нужна функция скрытия этого поля в форме? Отключить обязательное заполнение нельзя, выставить значение по умолчанию (через UI) нельзя.
...или можно?

Answer (score 0):

Возможность скрытия поля Title с формы редактирования сущности является багом ([Скрытие обязательных полей, которые не имеют значений по умолчанию, приводит к EntityStorageException (column cannot be null) при попытке сохранения](https://www.drupal.org/node/2821507)).

Выставить значение по умолчанию для лаблов сущностей через UI можно, например, с помощью модуля [Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel).